# Error: hangup in Gaussian 09

Tags: computational-chemistry, gaussian, geometry-optimization

I have the following problem to run a calculation using Gaussian 9. The calculation starts running and after a few hours stop. The `nohup` file has the following message:

```
error: hangup
rax fffffffffffffffc, rbx 00007fff0bd4e160, rcx ffffffffffffffff
rdx 0000000000000000, rsp 00007fff0bd4e128, rbp 00000000000000001
rsi 00007fff0bd4e160, rdi 000000000000828d, r8 00002b17bcdec700
r9 0000000000000000, r10 0000000000000000, r11 00000000000000246
r12 00007fff0bd4e180, r13 0000000000000064, r14 00000000000000000
r15 00007fff0bd54b40
--- traceback not available
```

In the logs of `/var/log/message` there is the following message:

```
Apr 19 20:28:10 ws1 abrt-hook-ccpp: Process 15059 (g09) of user 1002 killed by SIGABRT - dumping core
Apr 19 20:28:10 ws1 abrt-hook-ccpp: Process 15060 (l502.exe) of user 1002 killed by SIGABRT - dumping core
Apr 19 20:28:40 ws1 systemd-logind: Removed session 4.
Apr 19 20:28:40 ws1 systemd: Removed slice User Slice of xx.
Apr 19 20:28:41 ws1 abrtd: Size of '/var/spool/abrt' >= 5000 MB (MaxCrashReportsSize), deleting new directory 'ccpp-2022-04-19-20:28
:10-15060'
Apr 19 20:28:41 ws1 abrt-server: Lock file '.lock' is locked by process 12809. Waiting...
Apr 19 20:28:42 ws1 abrt-server: Generating core_backtrace
Apr 19 20:28:43 ws1 abrt-server: Duplicate: core backtrace
Apr 19 20:28:43 ws1 abrt-server: DUP_OF_DIR: /var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2022-04-01-10:32:53-214966
Apr 19 20:28:43 ws1 abrt-server: Deleting problem directory ccpp-2022-04-19-20:28:10-15059 (dup of ccpp-2022-04-01-10:32:53-214966)
Apr 19 20:28:43 ws1 abrt-server: Sender email address was not specified. Would you like to do it now? If not, 'user@localhost'
 is being used [y/N]
Apr 19 20:28:43 ws1 abrt-server: Receiver email address not specified. Would you like to do it now? If not, 'root@localhos
t' is being used [y/N]
Apr 19 20:28:43 ws1 abrt-server: Undefined variable outside of [[ ]] bracket
```

The input file settings:

```
%mem=20GB
%nprocshared=4
#p opt mp2/aug-cc-pvtz scrf=(solvent=acetonitrile,pcm) maxdisk=600GB
geom=connectivity density=current gfinput iop(6/7=3)
```

Doing the same calculation with PM6 worked fine. The problem only appears with highly demanding calculations, as optimization and frequency at MP2/aug-cc-pVTZ level. It no longer generates log files other than the ones I put.
Current machine settings is 93GB RAM and 32 CPUs. I don't know if it can be the machine's configuration, during the calculation the maximum memory it uses is 30GB.

Has anyone had this problem? Any idea what it could be? Here are the last few line of the log file.

```
 GePol: Maximum weight of points                     =    0.20577
 GePol: Number of points with low weight             =      78
 GePol: Fraction of low-weight points (<1% of avg)   =       4.99%
 GePol: Cavity surface area                          =    206.571 Ang**2
 GePol: Cavity volume                                =    211.021 Ang**3
 Leave Link  301 at Wed Apr 20 20:37:01 2022, MaxMem=  2684354560 cpu:         0.3
 (Enter /opt/ohpc/pub/apps/gaussian/09d01-pgi-14.3/g09/l302.exe)
 NPDir=0 NMtPBC=     1 NCelOv=     1 NCel=       1 NClECP=     1 NCelD=      1
         NCelK=      1 NCelE2=     1 NClLst=     1 CellRange=     0.0.
 One-electron integrals computed using PRISM.
```

Comment: About all you can tell from the above is your program has received a SIGABRT which has caused it to crash. The signal could occur from either a bug, or the program deliberately aborting as it encountered an error. I don't know Gaussian at all, has it reported an error in another file? But that's about all you can say from the above.

Comment: I suspect the reason for this error is the same as described [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/132616/how-to-fix-error-hangup-in-gaussian-16-modredundant-scan-calcuation) and that this an error of your system settings rather than directly from Gaussian. Can you include the last few lines of the log file in your question? Can you also try running the result with a semi empirical method (e.g. PM6) to see if you get the same error?

Comment: Seems most likely to be either an out of memory error (perhaps due to misconfigured memory allocation) or a problem writing temporary files to disc (quota exceeded or not enough local scratch space).

Comment: You can verify if it is a memory error trying to increase the RAM or reduce the number of nprocshared

Comment: This post appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if someone would like to answer or if OP addresses suggestions/questions from the comments.